# Make column as header and combine similar id in one row in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a query which output is something like the table below (see current output) wherein month is  a column. What i want is to place month name as Header and combine same itemcode and their quantity under which month it falls but in one row only.

Current output:

```
Itemcode    qty     month          
  001       200     Jan  
  001        50     Feb          
  002       100     Feb  
  002       100     Apr         
  003        50     Mar        
  003       200     Apr 
  004       300     Jan        
  004       100     Mar
```

This is what I want

```
  Itemcode   Jan      Feb     Mar   Apr ......        
  001        200       50         
  002                 100            100
  003                          50    200      
  004        300              100
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
ItemCode,
MAX(CASE `month` WHEN 'Jan' THEN qty END) AS Jan,
MAX(CASE `month` WHEN 'Feb' THEN qty END) AS Feb,
MAX(CASE `month` WHEN 'Mar' THEN qty END) AS Mar,
MAX(CASE `month` WHEN 'Apr' THEN qty END) AS Apr
FROM
Table1
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18d28/1/0).

MySQL does not have a handy `PIVOT` function like i.e. SQL Server, so you will have to live with code like above.

But in my opinion, output formatting should be done on application layer anyways, not in DB layer.